# Third-party P3P extension for Internet Explorer or Edge

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, p3p

P3P has been removed from Internet Explorer and Edge in Windows 10. Is there a third-party browser extension that, as a cookie filter, reads compact privacy policies and allows or blocks cookies based on the privacy policies? Just like Internet Explorer used to? An add-on for Internet Explorer or extension for Edge? That could be used on Windows 10?
Also, settings with a level as to how many cookies to block, just like what used to e in the Privacy tab of Internet Options. Or custom options to choose whether to allow or block cookies from sites with a certain tags in the compact policy.
Don't forget, a custom option to block first-party or only third-party cookies from sites that gather data that can be linked to me?

Also, are there any extensions like that for Firefox, Opera, Chrome, Brave, and browsers like those? That could be used on Windows, Linux, or Mac?